# Problems with sampling

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, discretization, sampling

Let $t\ge 0$ and let $f_{s}(t)$ be the sampled version of $f(t)$.

If $$f(t)=\begin{cases}\int_{0}^{t}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-s^{2}}\right)\,ds,&|s|<1,
\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

I used

```
Plot[NIntegrate[
Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], Abs[s] < 1}, {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}], {s, 
0, t}], {t, 0, 2}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

which is as I would expect.

Then we sample for arbitrary time interval $T=1/10$ to get

$$\begin{aligned}f_{s}(t)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n/10)\delta(t-n/10) \\ &=\begin{cases}\int_{0}^{n/10}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-s^{2}}\right)\,ds\cdot\delta(t-n/10),&|s|<1,
\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases} \end{aligned}$$

However, for the sampled function, when I use

```
DiscretePlot[
  Accumulate[ 
    Table[ 
      NIntegrate[ 
        Piecewise[
          {{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)]*DiscreteDelta[t - n*0.1], Abs[s] < 1}, 
           {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}], 
        {s, 0, n*0.1}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 20], 
      {n, -20, 20}]],
  {t, 0, 2}]
```

this yields:

[image]

which clearly isn't how it should look.

Moreover, when I attempt to perform a discrete time Fourier transform on the sampled data using

```
Plot[
  FourierSequenceTransform[
    NIntegrate[
      Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], Abs[s] < 1}, {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}], 
      {s, 0, 0.1 n}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 20], 
    {n, -20, 20}, 
    ω], 
  {ω, -20, 20}]
```

I fail to get the `n` in the `FourierSequenceTransform` argument, since it is in the integral limit, I think. But there must be a way to bypass this obstacle?

Comment: your formatted mathematical expressions don't make sense. Do you mean for the integral to be outside the piecewise expression (As it is in the mathematica form )?

Comment: @george2079 No, I don't, so thanks for pointing that out. However, using `DiscretePlot[
 Accumulate[
  Table[Piecewise[{{NIntegrate[Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], {s, 0, n*0, 1}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 20]*DiscreteDelta[t - n*0.1], Abs[s] < 1}, {0,
       Abs[s] >= 1}}], {n, -20, 20}]], {t, 0, 2}]` also fails to yield what I want.

Comment: your first plot is this right? `f[t_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], {s, 0, Min[1, t]}]`. That's not what your piecewise expression says..

Comment: @george2079 I actually used `Plot[NIntegrate[
  Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], Abs[s] < 1}, {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}], {s, 
   0, t}], {t, 0, 2}]`

Comment: With `DiracDelta` it's usually a good idea to use `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate` or just use `Sum` directly.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke I used your suggestions, but `DiscretePlot[
 Sum[Integrate[
   Piecewise[{{Exp[-(1/(1 - s^2))] DiscreteDelta[t - n 0.1], 
      Abs[s] < 1}, {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}], {s, 0, n 0.1}], {n, -20, 
   20}], {t, 0, 2}]` is also off.

Comment: its hard to follow what you are trying to do because your input formatted math expressions are basically nonsense.  You have an integral over `s` containing a delta function that does not depend on `s`..whats that supposed to do? The delta can be factored from the integral, but that makes the whole thing either zero or undefined depending on `t`.. (??)

Comment: @george2079 Yes, I can see your point. And what I am trying to do is get a discretised version of my original plot, based on the aforementioned equations. Whether the delta is in the integration or not is irrelevant, since as you mention it is independent of `s`. And when I put the integration in the piecewise then I get lots of errors using: `DiscretePlot[
 Sum[Piecewise[{{Integrate[Exp[-(1/(1 - s^2))], {s, 0, n*0.1}], 
      Abs[s] < 1}, {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}] DiscreteDelta[
    t - n*0.1], {n, -20, 20}], {t, 0, 2}]`

Comment: the result of your infinite sum is simply, if `10 t` is an integer `f[t]` else 0, the discretedelta should not appear in the next expression.

Comment: Do you mean discretizing like this: `ListPlot[Table[{t, 
   NIntegrate[
    Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], Abs[s] < 1}}], {s, 0, t}]}, {t, 0, 
   2, 1/10}]]` ?

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Yes, indeed. I am just surprised it is not working with the more formal delta expression.

Comment: Formally you can do stuff like `f[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], Abs[s] < 1}}], {s, 0, t}]; Integrate[
 Sum[DiracDelta[s - t] f[s], {t, 0, 2, 
   1/10}], {s, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`, i just don't get why the sum would make sense here, if you want to plot a discretized version of `f` afterwards. It would make more sense if you wanted to do convolution to express sampling on a discrete grid e.g.